# getting an attribute out of an xml

Tags: xml, actionscript-3

I have an XML that is structured like the following, I would like to get the currency attribute in AS3, regardless the SellTotosystem tag, because I will have different tags each time.

```
<GCPRequest version="1" requestId="1234567890">
<SellTotoSystem  currency = "EUR">

</SellTotoSystem>

</GCPRequest>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use one of the following example:

```
    var xml:XML = <GCPRequest version="1" requestId="1234567890">
            <SellTotoSystem  currency = "EUR"></SellTotoSystem>
        </GCPRequest>;

    var currency:String; 
    //first child at the first level of tree
    currency = xml.*.@currency[0];
    trace(currency);

    //first encounted child at any level of tree
    currency = xml..@currency[0];
    trace(currency);

//output:
EUR
EUR
```